# Configure java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Java and Eclipse are installed on my machine and its working fine. I want to configure java and eclipse on other machine.I have installed eclipse on other machine. I know I can make use of some portion of java installed on my machine to configure the java with eclipse on other machine. I don't know that exactly that which part of Java instalation on my machine is useful to configure java and eclipse on other machine.

Any help would be highly appriciated.
Thank you..!!

Comment: Reinstall the JDK from scratch. Don't try to copy an install from machine to machine.

Comment: Add java in path environment variable.

Comment: is java installed on your machine where new eclipse is on?